# Sphere cartopy gridspacing and Labeling

Tags: python, plot, 3d, cartopy, gridlines

I'm projecting a 2D map onto a sphere with cartopy and the gridlines keep doing what they want. Especially my xz perspective is messy!

I would love to place them like every 30° in both directions.

My code right now is like this

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(0, -90))
ax.gridlines(color='black', linestyle='dotted',linewidth='2')
ax.imshow(img, origin="upper", extent=(-180, 180, -90, 90),
          transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())  # Important
```

The image
[image]

Also I would love to label certain meridians like 270°

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/gridliner.html)? Manipulating gridlines using the return value of `ax.gridlines` seems straightforward enough (but I don't have cartopy installed). Have you tried that?

Comment: I think I did, but I will try it again, thanks!